# sorting alphabetically after stripping "the, a, an" only working partially

Tags: php, regex, symfony

Trying to hack apart an annoying bug here.

We have a regex which correctly strips off leading articles like "a", "the", etc.   It also sorts alphabetically fine for some of the entries, but not for the rest.   What happens is we get a list where some of the listings with these articles are embedded properly within the output, and then it gets to the end and starts over, with those entries correctly sorted among themselves.

Here's an example of how it's appearing

1. Apple
2. Banana
3. The Carrot
4. The Grapefruit
5. Kiwi
6. The aardvark
7. The emu
8. A zebra

As you can see, it does fine at first, but then gets to the end and starts over with *only* those items with articles.  I've looked at the data, and can't find any consistencies that would explain the variation.

Here's the regex comparison (in an entity called `Bibliography`)

```
    public static function compareTitles(Bibliography $a, Bibliography $b)
{
    $ignored_word_regex = '/^(the|a|an)\s/i';
    $tag_quote_regex = '/"?(\<\/?[a-zA-Z]+\>)?/';
    $a_test = preg_replace($ignored_word_regex ,'', $a->getTitle());
    $a_test = preg_replace($tag_quote_regex, '', $a_test);
    $b_test = preg_replace($ignored_word_regex ,'', $b->getTitle());
    $b_test = preg_replace($tag_quote_regex, '', $b_test);
    return strcmp( $a_test,
                   $b_test);
}
```

This is being pulled in from an entity called `Review`

```
    /**
 * @param Review $a
 * @param Review $b
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public static function compareTitles($a, $b)
{
    return \Entity\Bibliographies\Bibliography::compareTitles($a->getBiblio(), $b->getBiblio());
}
```

This is then sorted in the controller using these two methods:

```
    public function exportIndexTitleAction( Request $request ){
    $response = $this->renderExportXMLSorted(
        'Review:Export/index_title.xml.twig',
        $request,
        array('Entity\Reviews\Review', 'compareTitles'));
    return $this->setExportHeaders($response, date("o-m-d-")."index_title.txt");
}
```

and using a uasort:

```
    protected function renderExportXMLSorted($template, Request $request, $sort_method, $filter_method = null){
    $reviews = $this->getReviewsFromRequest($request);
    if ($filter_method != null)
        $reviews = array_filter($reviews, $filter_method);
    uasort($reviews, $sort_method);

    return $this->renderExportXML($template, $reviews);
}
```

I've been digging through this and cannot figure what causes it to stop and start over again. I can get it to sort fine if it treats "the" and "a" as they are, but they really need to be stripped, but also be displayed.  (yes, it would be easier to simply remove them, but they need to remain).

I'm thinking there's something in the regex that I'm missing...

Comment: You probably need to make `$sort_method` case insensitive.

Comment: Case is set to insensitive in the regex, and that's not really the issue (the examples I gave above are made up.  In each of the real world examples, they start with "A " "An " or "The ")

Comment: how about first parse changing them to `zebra, A` etc then you can sort regular style

Comment: `strcmp()` is not case insensitive. Replace it with `strcasecmp()`.

Comment: that would be an easier approach, yes.  Unfortunately, I need to follow the specs for the layout of these (they need to go into a publishable format as is)

Comment: If the list is relatively small, and If you can provide the sort function, you can use the regex in the sort function to capture everything but the leading articles. Can do this for A and B, then compare them.

Comment: @AlexHowansky thanks!  that was it.  If you write this as an answer, I'll mark it as the solved one (I see someone else did, but it was your suggestion I followed.)

Comment: Still this is a very slow way to do it. Possibly creating separate arrays ahead of time and working with indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously the problem is case.  You need to use `strcasecmp` to treat both cases the same.  You could also `strtolower` or `strtoupper` both before the compare. 
 Also, that is a lot of code that can be boiled down to something simpler:

```
uasort($array, function($a, $b) {
                     $p = '/^(the|a|an)\s/i';
                     $a = preg_replace($p, '', $a);
                     $b = preg_replace($p, '', $b);
                     return strcasecmp($a, $b);
               });
```

Comment: I know there's a lot of code;  it's part of a much larger app that I've been trying to reverse engineer, and have become a fan of the quick and dirty, and would rather not rewrite everything, despite the clunkiness of this thing ;)  (note we need to also pay attention to quotations that appear in titles... easier to read the regex this way)